# Read text file and name buttons VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

What I wan't to do is to read a text file with 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 lines.
If the text file is completely full (5 lines) then the code works.

But the code needs to work when there are only 3 lines in the text file.
So eventually you get 3 buttons with names and 2 without.

The code:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim Lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file)

        Dim Ordernummer1 As String
        Dim Ordernummer2 As String
        Dim Ordernummer3 As String
        Dim Ordernummer4 As String
        Dim Ordernummer5 As String

        Dim Regels As New List(Of String)
        Select Case Lines.Count
            Case 1
                Lines(1) = ""
                Lines(2) = ""
                Lines(3) = ""
                Lines(4) = ""
            Case 2
                Lines(2) = ""
                Lines(3) = ""
                Lines(4) = ""
            Case 3
                Lines(3) = ""
                Lines(4) = ""
            Case 4
                Lines.add(4) = ""
            Case 5
                'nothing

        End Select

        MsgBox(Lines(0))
        last = Lines(0).Substring(Lines(0).LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        MsgBox(last)
        Ordernummer1 = last.Substring(0, last.IndexOf(" "))
        MsgBox(Ordernummer1)
        Button12.Text = Ordernummer1

        MsgBox(Lines(1))
        last = Lines(1).Substring(Lines(1).LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        MsgBox(last)
        Ordernummer2 = last.Substring(0, last.IndexOf(" "))
        MsgBox(Ordernummer2)
        Button13.Text = Ordernummer2

        MsgBox(Lines(2))
        last = Lines(2).Substring(Lines(2).LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        MsgBox(last)
        Ordernummer3 = last.Substring(0, last.IndexOf(" "))
        MsgBox(Ordernummer3)
        Button14.Text = Ordernummer3

        MsgBox(Lines(3))
        last = Lines(3).Substring(Lines(3).LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        MsgBox(last)
        Ordernummer4 = last.Substring(0, last.IndexOf(" "))
        MsgBox(Ordernummer4)
        Button15.Text = Ordernummer4

        MsgBox(Lines(4))
        last = Lines(4).Substring(Lines(4).LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        MsgBox(last)
        Ordernummer5 = last.Substring(0, last.IndexOf(" "))
        MsgBox(Ordernummer5)
        Button16.Text = Ordernummer5
```

Comment: If you have added sixteen `Buttons` without changing the names to something meaningful then you're doing a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```vb
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim buttons = {Button12, Button13, Button14, Button15, Button16}

'Process lines and corresponding Buttons.
For index = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim line = lines(index)
    Dim btn = buttons(index)

    'Use line and btn here.
Next

'Process remaining Buttons if desired.
For index = lines.Length To buttons.GetUpperBound(0) Step 1
    'E.g.
    buttons(index).Hide()
Next
```

Comment: jmcilhinney, Would it be possible to say if a checkbox is checked delete that line from the text file?

Comment: @InventorTech20, that's a whole new question and something that you'd have to show that you've tried to do for yourself first. It's certainly possible but nothing to do with the subject of this question.